# Joy UI Modal - Background for the header only

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui, joy-ui

How can i change the background only for the header of a Modal in Joy UI with typescript?

Like in the following example:

[image: Modal example]

Or in general how can the modal be styled like in the screenshot above, thanks!

Already looked through documentation and other stackoverflow posts but couldn't find a good result.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We don't debug images here.